# In Qualtrics is there a coding solution to position multiple-choice response options on the edge of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, qualtrics

In my Qualtrics survey, I have a two-answer horizontal multiple-choice question and I am trying to reduce the distance between the response options and the edge of the screen (see the below image). For reference, I am using a blank Qualtrics theme.

II have tried using the following JS code which successfully decreased the inner padding between the response options, however, I have been unable to decrease the margin/padding outside the response options. I have also tried identifying which margin/padding element is causing the outside space by inspecting the page but with little-to-no HTML knowledge have been unsuccessful at doing so.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" label.SingleAnswer").css({"padding":"20px","display":"inline-block"});
});
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Henry

[image]

Comment: Without any working code example you can rarely get good answers. By the way
you can try float:left for the first element and float:right to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal choices are in a table. So:

- Make the table 100% wide
- Left align the first
- Right align the last cell